# sql server cannot create stored procedure sp_start_job

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a job I need to launch from a SP.  To do that I need a SP in my msdb system database called `sp_start_job`.  When I try to execute this code in SSMS:

```
Use msdb
go
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_start_job]
  [@job_name]
  [,@error_flag ] 
  [,@server_name] 
  [,@step_name ] 
  [,@output_flag ]
```

I get this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@job_name'.
```

This is all from the SQL books on line. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create the `sp_start_job` sproc, it should already exist in your **msdb** database.

You need to execute the stored procedure using the relevant parameters. For example:

```sql
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job
    'Your Job Name'; -- Add any other arguments if you need them
```

See the [MSDN documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) for further info.

Comment: It was not in the visible list so i thought i needed to add it.  and the error message really stinks!

Comment: The syntax error message is correct(not full, though) because there is no open parenthesis before procedure parameter declaration.